# Sending G-code through USB serial doesn't work (Ender 3)

Tags: g-code, creality-ender-3, raspberry-pi, serial-connection

Recently I was gifted an Ender 3 3D printer. I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi Zero W to send commands to the printer remotely, if I get this to work the idea is to instruct the RPi to pull G-code files over the internet and then send it to the printer. I read about Octoprint but they don't recommend using RPi Zero W with it, and also I want to learn more about programming (I just know Python), so if possible I'd like to avoid using it.

Here is what I've done:

- My RPi Zero W has Raspbian Buster Lite, so I'm using `SSH` to connect to it remotely. The pi is connected to the mini usb port on the printer.
- Once connected I located the serial of the printer, which is `ttyUSB0`.
- I verified the baud rate using `stty < /dev/ttyUSB0`, which was set to about 9600.
- I read on the internet that the Ender 3 controller has a baud rate of 115200, so I ran `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` and that worked fine.
- I tried sending the G-code to go to home position (`G28`) via serial using `echo "G28" > /dev/ttyUSB0`, but that just restarts the printer (the screen shows the logo and then returns back to the info screen). This persists even when sending different commands.

I tried opening another SSH session to read the output of the printer using `tail -f /dev/ttyUSB0`, but that again restarts the printer, and sending `echo` to it when `tail` is running won't do anything.