# Factory reset needed!

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware, reset

I have just bought a Creality Ender 3 Pro. During setup, I think I must have applied an offset... The nozzle lifts up about 5 mm from the bed when starting to print.

I am reading that `M502` resets to factory settings and `M500` saves the settings. I have looked everywhere I can think of but am unable to find these files to download.
Can someone help me please? Where can I find these files?

Comment: What "files" are you talking about? If you mean the `M502` and `M500`, those are commands that are sent to the printer. More info can be found at [What is a printer console/terminal?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal).

Comment: This could *potentially* be closed as a duplicate of  [What is a printer console/terminal?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/what-is-a-printer-console-terminal).

Answer (score 2):

`M502` and `M500` are not files, they are [G-code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code) commands (well, they are *actually* M-codes, but don't worry about that)<sup>1</sup>.

To reset your printer to the factory default settings, simply connect a [terminal](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/10573/4762) and send `M502`.

If you are using Linux, see [How to directly send G-code to printer from a Linux terminal?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/3112/4762)

See also [M502 will reset all configurable settings to their "factory defaults", which settings are those?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/11438/4762)

---

<sup>1</sup> Simply put: G-codes control movement; whereas M-codes control other functions (which aren't movements).